# How do I add a variable to ::class.java when using an Intent?

Tags: kotlin

```
   private fun showMember(member: Member) {
    val memberN: String = "" + member.name
    val moveIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, memberN::class.java)
    startActivity(moveIntent)
}
```

After some testing I found out that memberN::class.java crashes the app when I run the function. I tried using "" + and $ but it doesn't work.

I'm making a simple app which has a list of people and descriptions of them. When you tap on one of the objects on the list, it brings you to a page where you can read more about the person. As you can see from the code, each page is simply just the name of each person.

Comment: That is not how intents work. If you want to pass data to some activity you need to use extras in the Intent itself. The class an Intent takes is the class of the activity you want to start. Furthermore `memberN::class.java` will always be `String::class.java`.

Answer (score 0):

To get a `Class` by its name as a string, use `Class.forName()` e.g. `Class.forName(memberN)`.

Comment: Otherwise it's a little unclear what you're really trying to do here, i.e. what is the problem where a dynamic activity name like this would be a possible solution.